# Select yearBrth where count(yearBrth) > 4

Tags: phpmyadmin

How select from table column yearBrth where count(yearBrth) more than 4 (for exemple)

```
select 
    yearBrth
from 
    users 
where 
    count(yearBrth) > 4
-- group by yearBrth
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `having`

```
select yearBrth
from users 
group by yearBrth having count(yearBrth) > 3
```